# Application name in AndroidManifest when building with multidex=true

Tags: android, codenameone, android-multidex, parse4cn1

I have been trying to incorporate support for Parse Push in my app, following the instructions from [this wiki](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/wiki/Setting-Up-Push-For-Android) at GitHub. When building for Android, the last stumbling block was this error message in the build log:

> Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "application".

It turned out that the combination of the build hint

```
codename1.arg.android.multidex=true
```

and

```
codename1.arg.android.xapplication_attr=android\:name\="com.parse4cn1.nativeinterface.CN1AndroidApplication"
```

caused this problem. With multidex turned on, the application name becomes `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`

I solved it by setting `multidex` to `false`, but what if I needed it to be `true`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to the multi-dex process. The parse4cn1 wiki mentions changing `android.xapplication_attr` which I'm assuming you added the name attribute to. This is incorrect as it will inject the name into an activity that is already named.

Comment: I guess I haven't read the wiki thoroughly enough. It mentions the case where you already have an application class, which seems to be the case when `multidex=true`.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see that you found a solution to the problem. You mentioned that you're using Parse.com for push notifications. Please be aware that Parse.com is [shutting down soon](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/). At the moment, the open source Parse Server only supports push notifications for Android and iOS (not Windows Phone). Moreover, Parse Server introduces a [constraint](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push) that is not present in Parse.com, namely: The need to provide your app's master key in order to trigger push notifications from client side.

By design, `parse4cn1` does not perform any operations requiring the master key for security consideration. So if this constraint remains and client-triggered push is an interesting use case for you, you'll probably need to write server-side Javascript cloud code that you can then call using `parse4cn1` to trigger your push requests.

I'm currently in the process of updating `parse4cn1` to enable support for Parse Server. However, I don't think I'll update the push-related functionality in the next release. So please bear these possible constraints in mind as you move forward. If you're only interested in push notifications, you might also want to consider other dedicated push providers.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the master key issue in Parse Server. Maybe I will look into some of the other providers.